# Strange Behavior on New Theme Points to Idiocy

Tags: plugins, theme-development, errors

I was trying to block public access to my site while I developed a theme on a new domain. I was doing it with GD Press Tools' "Prevent website access if the user is not logged in" feature, because it's so damn easy to tick off a checkmark.

Strangely, it didn't work on my new theme.

You may say, "try another way of blocking public access", and I'd agree with you. But, it's worrying because it's not GD Press Tools' fault. The "prevent website access" feature is perfectly functional on the default twentyeleven theme. So basically I'm at fault somehow, and if GD Press Tools isn't liking it, I must've screwed up something major.

I've pastebin'd the entirety of my theme so far here. It's extremely bare and simple, consisting of index.php and style.css. *Note that pastebin isn't showing wp_head before the closing head tag, but it's there. My 404.php page is slightly custom, but commenting out the entirety of the file made no difference. You can view the code [here](http://pastebin.com/u/peed).

I have no idea what is going on here. Would you mind taking a look at my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin hooks `get_header()` to check if the user is logged in, your theme doesn't call `get_header()` so the check is never run.